Unable to add second account in existing profile in Outlook MAPI C++
I have a plugin developed in MAPI C++ which interacts with our server using SOAP APIs.
I am able to create profile and it works fine. But when I try to add second account of same server in existing profile by following below steps, it throws the error shown in below screen shot.
Open Outlook with existing profile configured->File->Account Settings->Account Settings->New

Any help why I am getting above error? Is it restriction from Outlook side?
Tried to look into different MAPI properties but it didn't help

Impossible to tell for sure without seeing the actual code and/or the service properties as displayed by OutlookSpy (I am its author - click IMAPISession | AdninServices), but my hunch is that your service's PR_RESOURCE_FLAGS specifies SERVICE_SINGLE_COPY bit.

Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko, Please see my below response for IMAPISession properties using OutlookSpy.

Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko, I found that in my there are below entries in my Mapisvc.inf file.

Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko, I found that in my there are below entries in my Mapisvc.inf file. In section
[LSMS]
PR_SERVICE_SUPPORT_FILES=LSMSCFG.DLL, LSMSSP.DLL, LSMSXP.DLL, LSMSUTIL.DLL
PR_SERVICE_ENTRY_NAME=LMServiceEntry
PR_RESOURCE_FLAGS=SERVICE_SINGLE_COPY|SERVICE_PRIMARY_IDENTITY
PR_SERVICE_DLL_NAME=LSMSCFG.DLL
Removed the entry SERVICE_SINGLE_COPY and allows me to add second account in same profile. But now my outlook is crashing. Is there anything else that needs to be changed along with this?

It is really impossible to tell without debugging the code. You need to be a lot more specific than "my outlook is crashing"

If your original question (cannot add a second instance of your provider) is answered, please mark the reply as answer. If you have an additional question, start a new thread and provide the relevant details.
